# Finding the correct possibility

Tags: python, math

The problem is :

```
Z=(89x-y) /10
```

There are 504 possibile combinations of X, Y and Z but only one is correct

Here's the code I wrote :

```
for x in range (1,10):
    for y in range (1,10):
        for z in range (1,10):
            if x=y or x=z or y=z :
                break
            print (x, y, z)
```

Comment: (1, 9, 8) = (x,y ,z)

Comment: My code isn't complete, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that you can use. No need for 3 loops; as one variable is dependent on other two.

```
>>> for i in range(1,10):
...     for j in range(1,10):
...             v =  (89*i - j)/10
...             if v == int(v) and 1<= v<= 9: print(i,j,int(v))
... 
1 9 8
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I don't see where do you use the relationship z=(89x-y)/10, hence we shouldn't expect your code to be able to find the solution. Also, to check for equality, use == rather than =.

Besides using two for loops as shown in the other solution, if we want to use maths to solve it, note that we have

89x - y = 10z

89x = 10z + y

Since we want to solve for a single digit solution that takes value from 1 to 9,  the right hand side is less than 100, and hence x must be 1. z is responsible for the ten place value and y must be the one place value.

Hence x=1, y = 9, and z = 8.